# How to encapsulate my Optaplanner program as a function for other platforms to call？

Tags: java, optaplanner

I have implemented a business problem using the tsp model in Optaplanner, and I can evaluate whether the sequence I entered is reasonable. Now because this function is to be used in actual production, I want to encapsulate the program for other platforms to call. How can I do it?
Looking forward to your reply! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [OptaPlanner Quickstarts](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts).
These are small applications where we show how to integrate OptaPlanner with the world. In your particular use case, you'll likely want to check out the [OptaPlanner School Timetabling quickstart](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/school-timetabling), which exposes REST endpoints over the solver using [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/).